# objective-c Unable to load nib file: RoosterView.xib

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, xib, nib

I changed my nib file by editing the info.plist file, and set the File's Owner to my class extending NSViewController, but now it gives me above error:

> Running…
>       2012-04-06 15:11:45.552 Rooster[1251:a0f] Unable to load nib file: RoosterView.xib, exiting
>
> ```
> Debugger stopped.
> Program exited with status value:1.(gdb)
> ```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Rooster is a Dutch word, I'm not talking about a male chicken.

Comment: I'm assuming that the file RoosterView.xib actually exists in your project?

Comment: Of course! It's in the same directory/folder as MainView.xib, the autogenerated xib.

Comment: What did you change in your info.plist?

Comment: from `MainMenu.xib` to `RoosterView.xib`

Comment: @Inafziger to notify you

Comment: Is the file name the same (including case)?  iOS is case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, it is, but perhaps it is because I created it illegal? I just created a new IB-file and then added it to my project, in the same folder as MainMenu.xib and altered the Rooster-Info.plist file. Perhaps somewhere else exists another setting YET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your info.plist file so that it loads your original nib (presumably, that was MainMenu.xib), and make sure that the File's Owner is `NSApplication`. In the vast majority of cases in which you're writing an application, this is how you want it.

Next, in your RoosterView.m (which I take to be a `NSViewController` subclass), load your RoosterView.xib using `NSViewController`'s `– initWithNibName:bundle:` method.

Finally, in your revived MainMenu.xib, add an Custom View object to your window. Make the Custom View's class that of your RoosterView.

Good luck to you in your endeavors. And in the future, whenever you're creating an application, please don't mess around with your application's xib's File's Owner settings, unless you enjoy a lot of frustration.

Comment: But don;t I get 2 main windows then?

Comment: Well, but your RoosterView is only that, a view. You need a window in which to display it, yeah?

Comment: I just edited my answer; it should make things a bit more clear.

Answer (score 18):

Another possible cause of this issue, is specifying "MainMenu.xib" instead of "MainMenu". That is, do not include the .xib extension.

When entering the filename in Xcode, it will auto complete and include the .xib which causes the error.

Comment: I had this same problem and it turns out this was the cause. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Same error occured me today. 
Fixed it with removing the .xib extension in the Project Settings under Main Interface.

Picture Tutorial:

Change this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: +1 for the included images. Helped me solve the problem in no time.